# substring_index store to session

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get only the domains from a list of emails. this is what i have:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT substring_index(email, '@', -1)";
$query .= " FROM `mailer_lists`";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $sending_domain[] = $row['email'];
  $_SESSION['sending_domain'] = $sending_domain;
}
```

Basically, it checks mailer_lists for all the domains I'm sending to.  All i want is for the domains that are in the `mailing_lists` table and store them into an array for the session. I've done something wrong in the while loop and I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the means to check that you are using `substring_index` correctly, but assuming you are...

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT substring_index(email, '@', -1) as email_domain";
$query .= " FROM `mailer_lists`";
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$sending_domain = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $sending_domain[] = $row['email_domain'];
}

$_SESSION['sending_domain'] = $sending_domain;
```

So the changes i made...

1. Put `as email_domain` in the query.
2. Creating the blank array in the beginning
3. Put the assignment to session outside the while loop where it belongs

I think the first two were just for form, but im more comfortable with them that way.  Step 3, taking the session assignment out of the loop, is what really matters.  It should only be done once when `$sending_domain` is filled.

Comment: right on i was missing 'as' in my sql query. that makes a lot of sense now. i'm also assuming that the $_SESSION inside the while loop would cause a lot of resource problems which explains why my server has been acting during each cron job.

Answer (score 2):

You want to set it *outside* of the loop.

```
$sending_domain = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $sending_domain[] = $row['email'];
}

$_SESSION['sending_domain'] = $sending_domain;
```